# Give list of numbers to determine which combination gives you a given value

Tags: c++

Ok so my programming skills are really novice and super rusty but here is my issue.  I need a way to take a list of given numbers and add them together in all combinations to determine which combo equals a certain amount.  My wife works at pepsi and they have to do this by hand and she asked me to help her out.  i will be attempting this with c++ if possible.  Thanks guys.

P.S. Here is the info i was given incase it helps.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9609070/Photo/Pepsi.tiff

Comment: Each number can be used once?

Comment: `std::next_permutation` might help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: It's going to take a while ; this problem is NP-complete

Comment: oh yea, forgot to mention that.  only once

Comment: I'm kind of wondering how successful they've been doing this by hand in the past.

Comment: Any reason why you chose c++ to do this?

Comment: using c++ bc thats all i know atm lol.  they have been very successful but it takes forever with many people working together.

Comment: I don't know the libraries, but maybe MATLAB or something more oriented to scientific computing would be useful here, as you are basically asking for every combination (not permutation) of a set, and then sum each, and compare.  That's where I'd start though, for N numbers, find every possible sub-combination of them.  Once you have that algorithm, it's pretty simple.  It's an algorithm problem, not as much a programming one.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and made a brute forcing thing. It'll get the job done if you leave it running for a long while, but definitely a lot faster than people. I used a list of integers to make it easier to test, so every int there should be a double.

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::accumulate;
using std::distance;
using std::includes;
using std::next_permutation;
using std::sort;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    const int wantedSum = 100; //this is your wanted sum here

    vector<int> v; //stores all of the numbers to choose from
    vector<vector<int>> matches; //stores combinations (no different ordering)

    ifstream inFile ("combination sum.txt"); //file to read values from

    int input;
    while (inFile >> input) //fill v with values
        v.push_back (input);

    inFile.close();

    for (vector<int>::size_type subSize = 1; subSize < v.size(); ++subSize) //go from 1 element at a time to the number to choose from
    {
        vector<int> sub (subSize); 
        sort (v.begin(), v.end()); //sort original vector

        do
        {
            for (vector<int>::iterator it = sub.begin(); it != sub.end(); ++it) //fill subvector with first n values in v
                *it = v.at (distance (sub.begin(), it));

            if (accumulate (sub.begin(), sub.end(), 0) == wantedSum) //check for sum
            {
                sort (sub.begin(), sub.end()); //sort subvector

                bool found = false; //check if same (but different order) as another
                for (const auto &element : matches)
                    if (includes (element.begin(), element.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end()))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }

                if (!found) //if it isn't the same as any
                {
                    matches.push_back (sub); //push sorted vector

                    cout << '{'; //output match

                    for (const auto &element : sub)
                        cout << element << ' ';

                    cout << "\b}\n";
                }
            }
        } while (next_permutation (v.begin(), v.end())); //go onto next permutation of v (this is what causes uber slowness as v's size grows)
    }
}
```

Input:

```
45
24
3
79
8
30
55
27
34
9
```

Output:

```
{45 55}
{3 8 34 55}
{9 27 30 34}
{3 9 24 30 34}
```

Execution time (yours will probably be higher): 0.840s

I'm not saying this is the best solution, but it works. Of course your list is quite large compared to the one I gave it so it will take a *lot* longer.

Oh, and some of this will take C++11 to compile. It might just be the ranged-for loops and the double right angle bracket. They can be fixed with

```
for_each (vec.begin(), vec.end(), some_func); //in algorithm
```

and

```
vector<vector<int> > v;
```

respectively. Cheers if this gets the job done in a reasonable amount of time.

Edit:

Replace `for (const auto &element : sub)...` with

```
for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = sub.begin(); it != sub.end(); ++it)
    if (includes (element.begin(), element.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end()))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
```

It would be replaceable with `std::for_each` if it weren't for the fact that you need access to `found` inside, so it's back to an explicit loop.

Comment: ah i see, that makes sense.  ill be using xcode unless i cant get it back working.  and you have it where it pulls values from a file correct?

Comment: Yes, my input is what was in my file.

Comment: i get "No member named 'accumulate' in namespace 'std'  Is it in another namespace?

Comment: My bad, it's in `<numeric>`, but still std. Also, I have thoughts that you might be able to make this multithreaded pretty easily. Each thread can have its own copy of `v` and specific `subSize`s to calculate. You can also be assured each having its own `matches` is fine since it's on a per-length basis. That should multiply the speed a bit, depending on how many cores you have.

Comment: that helped, also i get "declarations require type specifier" and "loop element may not be declared auto."  man i forgot this mess quick, i just had this last semester.  thanks for your help :)

Comment: `auto` is a C++11 keyword that automatically deduces the type based on the expression given. It's easier than writing out stuff like `vector<int>::const_iterator`. In C++03 all it does is make the variable's life just the scope it's in, which is the default if no specification is given. If you have C++03, you shouldn't need it at all in a `for_each` call.

Comment: i removed auto from that line and im still getting "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations."

Comment: Try putting `typename` in front of `vector<int>::iterator` and `vector<int>::size_type`.

Comment: with typename added i get one on both lines where i added that, and here for (cons &element : matches).

Comment: Oh, screw the typename, that was more of a guess this time. If you don't have C++11 (which I know now you don't) you have to replace the `ranged_for` AKA `for (element : container) do_something()` with a normal way of iterating through. Replacing it with `std::for_each (container.begin(), container.end(), do_something());` works best, but you can use explicit loops like you would normally as well.

Comment: I edited my answer with the necessary changes. The fact that it needs access to `found` excludes the possibility of `for_each` (at least in C++03).